# comparing two string arrays using java

Tags: java, arrays

we are trying to compare two string arrays( as[ ] and bs[ ]) and update the array string as[ ] with the new strings present in bs[ ] .We are not able to update the as[ ].Pls help us with the following codes.Thank u;)

```
public class Aa {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


  // Create an array of 4 strings (indexes 0 - 3)

    String as[] = new String[5];
    String bs[] = new String[16];
    int i;



    try {

        // Create a bufferreader object to read our file with.

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
       BufferedReader reader1;
        reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a1.txt"));


        // Line will hold our line read from the file
        String line = "";
        String line1 = "";


        // The counter will keep track of how many lines we have read

        int counter = 0;
        int counter1 = 0;


        // Read in a line from the file and store it in "line". Do this while we don't hit null or while the counter is less than 4.

        // The counter prevents us from reading in too many lines.

        while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null) && (counter < 4)) {

            as[counter] = line;

            counter++;

        }

        while (((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) && (counter1 < 16)) {

            bs[counter1] = line1;

            counter1++;

        }

         System.out.println("value"+as[0]);
          System.out.println("value"+bs[0]);
       int temp,temp1,j;
       temp=as.length;
       temp1=bs.length;
       System.out.println("length:"+temp);
       System.out.println("length1:"+temp1);
       for(i=0;i<bs.length;i++)
       {
           for(j=0;j<as.length;j++)
           {
               if(as[j].equals(bs[i]))
               {
                   //ignore
               }
               else
               {
                   temp++;
                   as[temp]=bs[i];

               }
           }

       }


        // With a foreach style loop we loop through the array of strings and print them out to show they were read in.



        reader1.close(); 
        reader.close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage()); }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not clear, what does it mean `update the array string as[ ] with the new strings present in bs[ ]`

Comment: If you are trying to append to the array, that does not work in Java. Arrays are fixed length.

Comment: `// Create an array of 4 strings (indexes 0 - 3)`: Don't forget to update your comments

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using two arrays **containing only strings**, its better to convert both to list and add

```
List aList = (Arrays.asList(as));
List bList = (Arrays.asList(bs));
bList.removeAll(aList); // assuming you have some common objects in both
aList.addAll(bList);
as = aList.toArray(); // Convert back to array
```

Comment: I am getting "unsupported operation exception"

Comment: Can you please share your code along with exception

Comment: bList.removeAll(aList); 
aList.addAll(bList);
as = (String[]) aList.toArray(as); 
for (aList a:list) {

   System.out.println(a);
   }           Im getting unsupported operation exception.How to print the contents of arraylist?

Comment: you should  use String[] as = (String[])aList.toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html):
You can use the combination of **contains** and a third temporary Array to store the differences (i.e. !contains).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{
    temp++;
    as[temp]=bs[i];
}
```

This doesn't work at Java as Thilo said in comments. You can not increase size of an array once its size is set.

I suggest to use `ArrayList` instead of `array`. You can simply add new items to an array list without any problem.

If you insist on using `arrays`, you can create a longer new array and copy your old array in here and add your new element. I wouldn't recommend this.